# Bionic Beaver - Gnome won't start with more than nvidia 6 GPUs

Tags: nvidia, gnome

Bionic Beaver - Gnome won't start with more than nvidia 6 GPUs.

It gives me an error in something called libmutter2.0.  Please let me know if I can provide more info to you.

If i disconnect one and restart, all is fine.

Comment: Have you found a workaround so far?